# Spring MVC cannot resolve .jsp files

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, view

I'm trying to build a RESTful Web Service. I followed the instructions from spring.io and made the "hello project" (localhost:8080/greeting) works. 
PS： I used the Maven project. The project is already published on Github: https://github.com/Tommzy/OutlierDemo/

However, when I was trying to let spring mvc resolve one of my view (.jsp). It's said

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Mar 25 01:31:04 EDT 2015 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

I'm not sure why this always happens, because I already have a config file as below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="config")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

The whole directory tree of my project is:

```
src-main|- java   |- config  |-  WebConfig.java

                  |- hello   |-  Application.java
                             |-  Greeting.java
                             |-  GreetingController.java
                             |-  PMethodController.java

        |- webapp |- WEB-INF |-  views   |-  pmethod.jsp
                             |-  web.xml
```

I copied the web.xml  from my friends. This file works fine on his project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-Dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>config</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-Dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and my PMethodController.java:

```
@Controller
public class PMethodController {

    @RequestMapping("/method1")
    public String handleRequest() {
        return "pmethod";
    }

}
```

My Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Depends on all above, if I run the project and then type http://localhost:8080/method1
It will show me the Whitelabel Error Page at the top of the page.

Comment: you can use `"org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"` as your viewResolver , [Check this out](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-view-resolver-example/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver(); 
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp"); 
    return viewResolver;
}
```

Comment: Hi! I tried your code, however the TemplateResolver cannot imported to the project. I'm working on a maven project, do I need to add more stuff to  the pom.xml to make it work?

Comment: Hey sorry added wrong code, just updated new one. check it and let me know.

Comment: </3 still not working, but I think we are almost there.

Comment: ya hope so. let me check and get back to you.

Comment: Yap! I just publish my project on the github, here is the link: https://github.com/Tommzy/OutlierDemo/

Comment: nop, there's no source code file there. there's only `.ignore` files.

Comment: Sorry! I just upload my project!

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a complete, simple, [working example of JSPs with Spring Boot in the spring-boot-samples repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jsp).

A few ideas to fix your app:

- delete your WebConfig and paste the `InternalResourceViewResolver` in your Application class. It's not picked up anyway because you're not scanning that package
- delete your web.xml file